# Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'gpa' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

I am currently struggling with an error for a homework assignment in my coding class. We are creating a loop that loops through an array of gpa values and then adds it to a variable named totalGradePoints. The problem is that I am coming across an error when the loop runs:

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'gpa' is a 'let' constant

The error is on this line:

```
var totalGradePoints = Double()
for gpa in gpaValues {
    let averageGPA: Double = gpa += totalGradePoints
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

// You are the university registrar processing a transfer student's transcripts that contains grades that are a mix of letters and numbers. You need to add them to our system, but first you need to convert the letters into grade points.
// Here's an array of the student's grades.

var transferGrades: [Any] = ["C", 95.2, 85, "D", "A", 93.23, "P", 90, 100]

// To prepare for converting the letters to numerical grades, create a function that returns a double, inside which you create a switch that will convert an A to a 95, B to 85, C to 75, D to 65, , P (for passing) to 75. Everything else will be a zero.

func gradeConverter(letterGrade: String) -> Double {
    switch letterGrade {
    case "A":
        return 95
    case "B":
        return 85
    case "C":
        return 75
    case "D":
        return 65
    case "P":
        return 75
    default: // Is this where everything else is zero?
        return 0
    }
}

// Create a new array called convertedGrades that stores doubles.
var convertedGrades: [Double] = [98.75, 75.5, 60.0, 100.0, 82.25, 87.5]

// Loop through the transferGrades array, inspecing each item for type and sending strings (your letter grades) to the function you just made and storing the returned double in your convertedGrades array. If your loop encounters a double, you can place it directly into the new array without converting it. It it encounters an int, you will need to convert it to a double before storing it. Print the array. (You may notice that some of your doulbes are stored with many zeros in the decimal places. It's not an error, so you can ignore that for now)

for grade in transferGrades {
    if let gradeAsString = grade as? String {
        gradeConverter(letterGrade: gradeAsString)
    } else if let gradeAsDouble = grade as? Double {
        transferGrades.append(gradeAsDouble)
    } else if let gradeAsInt = grade as? Int {
        Double(gradeAsInt)
        transferGrades.append(gradeAsInt)
    }
}
print(transferGrades)

// Now that we have an array of numerical grades, we need to calculate the student's GPA. Create a new array called GPAValues that stores doubles.

var gpaValues: [Double] = [2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 3.12, 2.97, 2.27]

// Like with the letter conversion function and switch you created before, make a new function called calculateGPA that takes a double and returns a double. Inside your function, create another switch that does the following conversion. Grades below 60 earn zero grade points, grades in the 60s earn 1, 70s earn 2, 80s earn 3, and 90s and above earn 4.

func calculateGPA(gpaValue: Double) -> Double {
    switch gpaValue {
    case 0..<59:
        return 0
    case 60...69:
        return 1
    case 70...79:
        return 2
    case 80...89:
        return 3
    case 90..<100:
        return 4
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

// Loop through your convertedGrades array and append the grade point value to the GPAValues array. Because your calculateGPA function returns a value, you can use it just like a varialbe, so rather than calculate the grade points and then put that varialbe in your append statement, append the actual function. i.e. myArray.append(myFunction(rawValueToBeConverted))

for gpa in gpaValues {
    gpaValues.append(calculateGPA(gpaValue: gpa))
}

// Finally, calculate the average GPA by looping through the GPA and using the += operator to add it to a variable called totalGradePoints. You may need to initialize the variable before using it in the loop. i.e. var initialized = Double()

var totalGradePoints = Double()
for gpa in gpaValues {
    let averageGPA: Double = gpa += totalGradePoints
}

// Count the number of elements in the array (by using the count method, not your fingers) and store that number in a variable called numberOfGrades. Pay attention to creating your variables with the right types. Swift will tell you if you're doing it wrong.

var numberOfGrades: Int = gpaValues.count

// Divide the totalGradePoints by numberOfGrades to store in a variable called transferGPA.

var transferGPA: Double = Double(totalGradePoints) / Double(numberOfGrades)

// Using code, add one numerical grade and one letter grade to the transferGrades array that we started with (i.e. append the values rather than manualy writing them into the line at the beginning of this file) and check that your transferGPA value updates. You'll need to append the new grades on the line below the existing transferGrades array so that your changes ripple through the playground.

transferGrades.append(97.56)
transferGrades.append("B")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`averageGPA` must be define using the `var` keyword to make it mutable later on when summing up the values.

```
var averageGPA: Double = 0
for gpa in gpaValues {
    averageGPA += gpa
}   
averageGPA = averageGPA / Double(gpaValues.count)
```

Recall the average is calculated by summing up the score and dividing the number of scores.

Defining something with `let` means that the following will be a constant.

```
let answer: Int = 42
answer = 43 /* Illegal operation. Cannot mutate a constant */
```

Comment: This is what I needed to fix my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'gpa' is a 'let' constant

The problem is that gpa is a constant, you can't modify its value. And the "+=" operator means "increase gpa's value by totalGradePoints", it is trying to increase the value of gpa. What you probably mean to do is make averageGPA equal the sum of gpa and totalGradePoints. For that you would do this:

```
 let averageGPA: Double = gpa + totalGradePoints
```

Comment: There's a lot more to be fixed than just removing the `=`. `averageGPA` isn't even used. And the value being assigned certainly isn't any kind of average.